# CPanel - open inner link directly settings

Tags: server, cpanel

My angular routing in working properly on local.

When i am opening inner-link directly, i  get 404.

Ex domain.com/abc/5

I get page not found error.

Where to do settings for inner link directly?
I can't find settings for the same.Can anyone guide?

Comment: do you have an app-routing.module.ts file?

Comment: we need more details